# Looking for hadith about people who suffered in this world

Tags: hadith, reference-request

For my studies I need to know whether there are reliable ahadith about people who suffered (even maybe killed, or whatever) in this world, but in Hereafter they were extremely happy and considered themselves extremely lucky that they suffered so much in this world. Because, after all, it was for a limited time, and because they suffered so much they are going to go to the Paradise. And had they given the opportunity again, they would again opt for suffering no matter how much.

(Once I heard, I think a hadith, that those children who suffered in this world and were killed, like those Palestinian children, would say that they were meant to go to Paradise anyway but their condition was a test for others---whether other Muslims would help or not. Whether true or not, it gave me the idea that there may be other such ahadith.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *sahīh* (authentic) hadith that I know of to the exact meaning of what you are asking about. There are lots of authentic hadiths about the rewards Muslims get in the Hereafter for their pain and suffering in this world. There are two hadiths that are commonly referred to in this context, though.

The first hadith is a *hassan* (good) hadith in Jami' at-Tirmidhi, and was also narrated (very similar wording) by Ibn Mas'ūd in [*Al-Mu'jam al-Kabir*](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1733/10814) by At-Tabarani and by Masrūq in [*Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaiba*](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/39481):

> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ حُمَيْدٍ الرَّازِيُّ، وَيُوسُفُ بْنُ مُوسَى الْقَطَّانُ الْبَغْدَادِيُّ، قَالاَ حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ مَغْرَاءَ أَبُو زُهَيْرٍ، عَنِ الأَعْمَشِ، عَنْ أَبِي الزُّبَيْرِ، عَنْ جَابِرٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ يَوَدُّ أَهْلُ الْعَافِيَةِ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ حِينَ يُعْطَى أَهْلُ الْبَلاَءِ الثَّوَابَ لَوْ أَنَّ جُلُودَهُمْ كَانَتْ قُرِضَتْ فِي الدُّنْيَا بِالْمَقَارِيضِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ وَهَذَا حَدِيثٌ غَرِيبٌ لاَ نَعْرِفُهُ بِهَذَا الإِسْنَادِ إِلاَّ مِنْ هَذَا الْوَجْهِ ‏.‏ وَقَدْ رَوَى بَعْضُهُمْ هَذَا الْحَدِيثَ عَنِ الأَعْمَشِ عَنْ طَلْحَةَ بْنِ مُصَرِّفٍ عَنْ مَسْرُوقٍ قَوْلَهُ شَيْئًا مِنْ هَذَا ‏.‏
>
> Jabir narrated that the Prophet (s.a.w) said: "On the Day of Judgement, when the people who were tried (in this world) are given their rewards, the people who were pardoned (in life), will wish that their skins had been cut off with scissors while they were in the world." This Hadith is Gharib, we do not know of it with this chain except through this route. Some of them have reported something similar to this Hadith from Al-A'mash, from Talhah bin Musarrif from Masruq.
>
> <sub>— [Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Book 36, Hadith 100](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/36/100)</sub>

There is another hadith in *Al-Mu'jam al-Kabir*, but it is graded *daʻīf* (weak) as it has Mujjā'a ibn az-Zubair, whom [Ad-Daraqutni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Daraqutni) considered weak in hadith:

وفيه مجاعة بن الزبير وثقه أحمد وضعفه الدارقطني‏

> حَدَّثَنَا السَّرِيُّ بْنُ سَهْلٍ الْجُنْدِيسَابُورِيُّ، ثنا عَبْدُ اللهِ بْنُ رُشَيْدٍ، ثنا مُجَّاعَةُ بْنُ الزُّبَيْرِ، عَنْ قَتَادَةَ، عَنْ جَابِرِ بْنِ زَيْدٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ قَالَ: يُؤْتَى بِالشَّهِيدِ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ فَيُنْصَبُ لِلْحِسَابِ، وَيُؤْتَى بِالْمُتَصَدِّقِ فَيُنْصَبُ لِلْحِسَابِ، ثُمَّ يُؤْتَى بِأَهْلِ الْبَلَاءِ، وَلَا يُنْصَبُ لَهُمْ مِيزَانٌ، وَلَا يُنْشَرُ لَهُمْ دِيوَانٌ فَيُصَبُّ عَلَيْهِمُ الْأَجْرُ صَبًّا حَتَّى إِنَّ أَهْلَ الْعَافِيَةِ لَيَتَمَنَّوْنَ فِي الْمَوْقِفِ أَنَّ أَجْسَادَهُمْ قُرِضَتْ بِالْمَقَارِيضِ مِنْ حُسْنِ ثَوَابِ اللهِ لَهُمْ
>
> <sub>**NOTE.** My own translation, so treat with care.</sub>
>
> Ibn 'Abbas narrated that the Prophet ﷺ said: "A martyr is brought forth on the Day of Judgment for his reckoning, and a donator of charity for his reckoning, then the people of suffering are brought forth and no scale is set up for them and no records are spread, then the rewards pour on them that the people who were healthy in their worldly life wish in this situation if their skins had been cut off with scissors from the amount of rewards from Allah that they [those with sufferings] get.
>
> <sub>— [Al-Mu'jam al-Kabīr, Vol. 12, pp. 182, Hadith 12829](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1733/14955)</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I am confused about one thing (my ignorance perhaps). You said *The first hadith is a hassan*, then, after the first hadith, you said *This Hadith is Gharib*. So is the first hadith reliable or not? Further, the second (weak) hadith sounds a lot like the first one (*their skins had been cut off with scissors*).

Comment: @blackened usually gharib is a kind of ahaad a hadith that has been narrated only through a single chain. But in cases at-Thirmidi uses this term to point at a strangeness in the content -which indeed could be a weakness-, but it seems that the first is the case here.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Is * if their skins had been cut off* an Arabic idiom? What exactly does it mean?